# Close Popover and open new one with one tap

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

Apple's "Mobile Human Interface Guidelines" says about Popovers:

> **When possible, allow people to close one popover and open a new one
>   with one tap.** This behavior is especially desirable when several
>   different bar buttons each open a popover, because it prevents people
>   from having to make extra taps.

The only solution I can think right now is to track the position of the touch when dismissing the popover and check whether that was the position of another button. 
Is there any easier way to do this?

PS: I searched in stackoverflow and googled quite a while before posting. Sorry, if this was asked here before.

**UPDATE**

I guess I didn't explain myself well. Let's say I have three buttons. All of them open a popover. My user taps button #1 and a popover opens. While the popover is open, the user taps button #2. The popover gets dismissed (because the user tapped outside of the popover - default behavior of non-modal popovers) and a new popover opens up because the user had clicked on button #2. All of that without having to tap twice: once to dismiss the popover and twice for opening the new one.

**2nd UPDATE**

I built a simple dummy to reproduce what I'm trying to do. When the user taps on a button and a popover is open, the method that opens the popovers doesn't get called. Therefore the user has to click twice to open the second popover. Any ideas?

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController() 

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *currentPopover;

@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize currentPopover;

- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];

    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 40);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %i", i + 1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openPopover:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setFrame:buttonFrame];
        [view addSubview:button];

        buttonFrame.origin.y += 50;
    }


    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}

- (IBAction)openPopover:(id)sender
{
    AViewController *avc = [[AViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:avc];
    [avc release];

    UIPopoverController *tempPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
    [tempPopover setDelegate:self];
    [tempPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
    [tempPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];

    self.currentPopover = tempPopover;
    [tempPopover release];


    [navigationController release];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [currentPopover release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use bar button items in a toolbar, the open popover is **not** automatically closed when you tap another bar button item. In these situations you should close the visible popover and open the other one in one step.

Comment: I'm not using a toolbar but a bunch of UIButtons. Is it then the same? That'd be strange. My popovers behave differently.

Comment: Yes, it behaves differently. If you don't use a toolbar, you don't have that problem. You can try that easily for yourself, put two UIBarButtonItems in a toolbar, that both open a popover. If you push the second button the first popover is *not* closed (although tap is outside first popover). In these cases you have to do your own popover management.

Comment: But since I'm not using a toolbar, I don't have that "problem". I would be happy to have that problem, though. In that case, I could just close the popover and open a new one. In my case, I don't seem to get any touch events for the buttons while the popover is open. You can check the code that I just posted.

Comment: The UIPopoverController has a property called: passthroughViews. You can register your button(s) there and get events. Just look into the docs.

Comment: I had read the docs but it seems like I oversaw that property. That was exactly was I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)sortAction {
[searchBarView resignFirstResponder];
[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; //clear popover

self.popoverController = popoverSetting;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sortBarButtonItem
                               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //show popover
}
```

hope will help you

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have 3 buttons and each opens a popup.  You could use a state variable that tracks whether a popup is currently open, and inside each "open popup" method, close the existing one (if it is open) before opening the new popup.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself well. Let's say I have three buttons. All of them open a popover. My user taps button #1 and a popover opens. While the popover is open, the user taps button #2. The popover gets dismissed (because the user tapped outside of the popover - default behavior of non-modal popovers) and a new popover opens up because the user had clicked on button #2. All of that without having to tap twice: once to dismiss the popover and twice for opening the new one.

Comment: I don't want to use a modal popover. I think it's nicer if the user doesn't have to click twice to open a new popover.

Comment: they wont have to click twice.  The single click on the button, will close the existing open modal (if one is open) and then open the new modal.  just code the method to do both

Comment: Then something is wrong in my code. If I have a modal popover open, the method that opens the popovers doens't get called once a button is tapped. That's why I thought that taps didn't get registered when a popover is open. Maybe I should build a little dummy as test...

Comment: I built a dummy and I have the same problem with it: the method that open the popovers doesn't get called when a popover is open. I'll post the code.